# What's the material-ui <select> equivalent of <input type="color"><datalist>?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to javascript, react, and Material-UI so my question (and code sample) may be naive.

I have the following code in a Material-UI TableCell (not a form):

```
<input type="color" name="backgroundColor" list="categoryColours" id="categoryColour"/>
<datalist id="categoryColours">
{colourOptions.map((val) =>`<option value=${val.value}>${val.value}</option>`)}
</datalist>
```

I like the colour picker it produces (it renders the 25 colour swabs in a nice grid), but I would like to replace this with the appropriate Material-UI component. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use material-ui-color. It's not part of the Material-UI library, but it is a compatible module that can do both colour picker and colour swabs.

The current URL is https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-color.

The provided example is:

```
<div>
    <ColorPicker defaultValue="black" palette={paletteObj} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a package for Material UI v5 (or MUI) called [Mui color input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-color-input) and it's working with React 17 and 18 !

Simply way to use. Color validation available too.

Check the doc here : https://github.com/viclafouch/mui-color-input

```js
import React from 'react'
import { MuiColorInput } from 'mui-color-input'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('#ffffff')

  const handleChange = (newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue)
  }

  return <MuiColorInput value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
}
```